# Can we put VF page as related list to Another VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce

Can we put one VF page as related list to Another VF page in customer portal. if it is possible can any one say me how it can be done.

Comment: You could just embed it inside the VF page using apex:include ?

Comment: how to write the code for that i haven't dont it before can u please guide me little bit more

Comment: can we set vf page to customobject as relatedlist only in custom potal is that possible to do

Answer (score 2):

Take a loot at http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_include.htm

Sure it will help, there is an example aswell.

Comment: i saw the link it real good as a new stater i was dit confused with the text in it

Comment: If you're a starter in SF and using Chrome, I recommend installing Force.com Utility Belt: http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/force-com-utility-belt/

Comment: please keep voting if answers are helpful and check it if answer is true and you are satisfied that its the best answer

Comment: do we need to give the url id's of pages in <apex:page>